# Copy CSV content to another CSV

Tags: ruby, file, csv, copy

I'm trying to copy the content of a CSV file to another one.

First attempt:

```
FileUtils.cp(source_file, target_file)
```

Second attempt:

```
CSV.open(target_file, "w") {|file| file.truncate(0) }
CSV.open(target_file, "a+") do |csv|
 CSV.foreach(source_file, :headers => true) do |row|
  csv << row
 end
end
```

Third attempt:

```
CSV.open(target_file, "w") {|file| file.truncate(0) }
File.open(source_file, "rb") do |input|
 File.open(target_file, "wb") do |output|
  while buff = input.read(4096)
   output.write(buff)
  end
 end
end
```

Nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

When I run from Terminal `cp source_file target_file`, the target file is correctly created/copied. But in my app it is just creating the `target_file`, without any content.

Comment: Why not bypass all that and use [`FileUtils.cp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp)?

Comment: @muistooshort  FileUtils.cp(source_file, target_file) still nothing happening

Comment: Are `source_file` and `target_file` what you expect them to be? How specifically do you know that nothing is happening? Are you sure you're looking in the right directory?

Comment: `CSV.open(target_file, "w") {|file| file.truncate(0) }` is correctly deleting the file content. next lines are not copying the content from one file to another. so it seems like I'm looking in the right directory @muistooshort

Comment: If you open the file for writing (rather than appending) then it will erase the file's content so what happens if you skip the manual truncation? Have you tried to debug this by watching what `buff` contains during the iteration?

Comment: I just added `p File.zero?(source_file)` and it returns true! but the .csv is obviously not empty. that's strange. @muistooshort

Comment: Do you have these files open anywhere else?